# Why my Prometheus consumes huge storage of disk without continuous data write?

Tags: prometheus

I download the Prometheus source code from GITHUB, and followed by the tutorial to make build this project. Fortunately, I get the executable file. But I immediately encounter the terrible thing that the usage of my disk is 100%.

Next, I found the reason is the `data/chuns_head` folder generates many files, named by 0000xx. I just run the `./prom --config.file=prome.yml` and do nothing after that. However, the Prometheus continuously depletes my disk.

Here is my `prome.yml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:

rule_files:

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'rundb'

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

Here is the picutres of chunks_head and my disk(only 15% at the very beginning).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Until now, the only method to solve this problem is to redownload the source code and make build it again, and then you should run it for a while with watching that whether the prome generates the chunks_head folder, if not, Congratulations! If exist, try it again.

Except for this idiot way, the [official solution](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/7305) is investigating now.